# Using :before/:after Selectors to add Margins Around Elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I implemented (a modified version of) Gene Locklin's 'depth' which works just fine, here's the code:

```
body:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 110%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    z-index: 6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    content: "";
}
```

But I would like to use the :before & :after selectors to add margins or padding, you know some kind of gap, to separate a form from the surrounding text.

This comes after me trying to use these selectors to give some spacing around specific paragraphs, without success I turned to styling these on the basis of their target attributes.

I realize that the selectors were designed primarily to facilite auto-text and that it's perfectly easy to do this with margins or padding (added following queries below),line breaks, spans, an empty division, or even using JavaScript to create an element, and . But I would like to do this with :before & :after.

Here's the example code that I would like to get working:

```
form:before {
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
}

form:after {
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    }
```

Possibilities I think may be preventing this from working... :before/:after need to be displayed as block-level as they are normally inline (but the 'depth' doesn't need this?) and/or :before/:after require absolute positioning.

Thank you in advance for your generous input.

Comment: Something wrong with the margin property?

Comment: I'm with Animuson... why are you attempting to use psuedo-elements to add faux padding? Just use the `margin` and `padding` properties correctly...

Comment: Absolutely, why is `form { margin: 20px auto; }` not working for you?

Comment: It would work perfectly, margins & padding were two methods I neglected to include in the paragraph which begins "I realize...". I just wanted to get these pseudo-elements working for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try specifying `display: block;`. They don't need to be `position: absolute;`.

```
form:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}

form:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you specify it to be `display: block` it will already imply a 'width 100%' (expanding to fill the available width). Don't be redundant, please.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Supposing it works, because display:block is required, does the 'depth' code work on the principle that it inherits the 'display:block' from the body element?

Comment: The `display` property is not inherited.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, it always seems to be the case that as I'm writing the question, thoughts come to mind about the answers.

Comment: Did some testing...:before & :after don't show without also using display: block or position: absolute/position: fixed with a width declared