# Why css before element automatically adds bottom positioning of -1px

Tags: css, alignment, pseudo-element

I am trying to align two boxes with same dimensions. The first is a div and second is the `:before` pseudo-element of the div, but for some reason the pseudo-element is positioned with -1px at the bottom and the boxes are not aligned. I can't understand why that is. It seems the browser add a positioning distance for no reason and when border is removed it all works. Is this a browser bug or I am doing something wrong.

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
}

div::before {
 position:absolute;
 content: '';
 left: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: My guess is that it's because of the 1px border

Comment: But they both have the same 1px border

Comment: You were right if I remove the border it works, but still dont get why border is a problem in this case.

Comment: It may be possible that `left: 50px;` is overlapping with border. Try `left: 51px;`

Comment: I did no change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using :before/:after Selectors to add Margins Around Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479184/using-before-after-selectors-to-add-margins-around-elements)

Comment: I dont see the relation between the two posts. In his case he is having a margin problem here there is no margin if you inspect the lement you will see there is no margin or pading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<div>`'s content is only whats inside of the border. The border itself is not part of the `<div>`'s content which the `::before` is relatively positioned to. The `::before` behaves as expected because its `top` position is relative to the `<div>`'s content-area, not the `<div>` including its border. If you change the border to 2px you will notice the difference will be 2px then. A `top` of -1px would indeed fix this issue, but not in a generic way.

The best way to fix this issue is by using a container `<div>` serving as the relative block instead of the owning `<div>` of the `::before`:

```css
    .container {
      position: relative;
    }
 
    .inner {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid;
    }

    .inner::before {
   position:absolute;
      top: 0;
   content: '';
   left: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="inner"></div>
    <div>
```

Another way would be to use an `outline` value or a box-shadow: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;`. These don't affect the size of the `<div>` using it.